# If a minimization task is a convex optimization problem, is its maximization also convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

If a **minimization** task is a convex optimization problem, is the **maximization** of the same objective function also always a convex optimization problem?

My guess is yes since minimization of the negative of the objective function is maximization, but wondering if there are cases that outdo, and disprove, this sign 'trick'

Comment: Note that the "negative" of a convex function will not usually be convex  (because changing signs reverses the direction of the inequality).

Comment: No. In fact very often the minimization task is convex ("easy" to solve) while maximization is computationally extremely hard.

Answer (score 2):

$$\min x^2,$$$$ -1 \le x \le 1$$ is convex.

If you consider $$\max x^2 ,$$$$ -1 \le x\le 1,$$

It is clearly not convex, in particular, it attains the maximum at the boundary but if we interpolate it, we do not get an optimal solution in between.

Comment: can you provide an example that doesn't impose constraints on the decision variable $x$

Comment: just remove the constraint then, that would give you an example.

Comment: but min $x^2$ and max $x^2$ would both be convex functions, which changes the validity of your answer

Comment: $\max x^2 = - \min (-x^2)$, check that $-x^2$ is not convex.

Comment: does $-$min$(-x^2)$ = min $x^2$?

Comment: no, as we move the negative sign outside, minimization becomes maximization

Comment: yes, so why did you bring in $-$min$(-x^2)$ when it wasn't in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115103/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-develarist).